# No Bibtex output

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, thesis

I am trying to use bibtex in a [thesis template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), but it seems to give absolutely no output. Using the bibtex command gives me the output "I couldn't open file name ref.bib.aux", where ref.bib is the name of the bibtex database. On the other hand, using "Quick Build" in texmaker produces the output file, but without the references. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked http://www.latextemplates.com/forums#/discussion/232/cannot-generate-the-bibliography

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, but it does not seem to help. As I said, executing bibtex gives me an error message.

Comment: I have downloaded the zip from the path and done the following: Step 1: `pdflatex main.tex`. Step 2: `bibtex main`; Step 3: `pdflatex main.tex`; Step 4: `pdflatex main.tex`. Thatz it! `PDF` generated with reference. Can you try this.

Comment: Did you give `bibtex ref.bib`. That might be the problem. Instead give `bibtex <filename>`.

Comment: You should not give bibtex the name of the `.bib` file but eh name of the latex document (without the .tex extension) for which you need to generate a bibliography.

Comment: @blackburn Yes, it was a mistake. It is working now. However, using "Quick Build" on Texmaker still does not work.

Comment: Which option is selected for quick build? (Options --> Configure Texmaker --> Quick Build)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. pdflatex

Comment: Right, so it doesn't run BibTeX, which is required. In my version on Texmaker none of the predefined Quick Build options include BibTeX, so you'd have to create custom one: select 'User' and then click the 'Wizard' button on the right. Add pdfLaTeX once, then BibTeX, then pdfLaTeX twice. It should add something like `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 %.tex|bibtex %|pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 %.tex|pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 %.tex` in the text field.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you. I have used your method and now it works perfectly.